# Group Theory: Is an X-cycle of order X?

Tags: group-theory

That is in for instance $A_5$ is a 5-cycle, say $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$ of order 5? Are those two phrasings equivalent, ie do they mean the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An $n$-cycle is of order $n$ because its $n$th power is the first power that equals the identity. Not all permutations of order $n$ are necessarily $n$-cycles though